# Incorrect aligment of columns with different heights in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap in all my projects, but my problem always is that when the columns have different heights, they don't align correctly, specifically the columns don't align one below other.

I want resolve this problem without use a library like isotope or masonry, or any other similar library.

Suppose we have this code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="item-product">
            <h4>Product Title</h4>
            <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="item-product">
            <h4>Product Title</h4>
            <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="item-product">
            <h4>Product Title</h4>
            <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="item-product">
            <h4>Product Title</h4>
            <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example when the images have different heights also modifies the height of the column, that's where the problem occurs. I hope I explained.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your example isn't a working link

Comment: Please include your code example in the question instead. Please do not use links to external sites to provide necessary detail for your question; a StackOverflow question should be entirely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use CSS column-width like this..

```
.row {
 -moz-column-width: 25em;
 -webkit-column-width: 25em;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
}

.row > .col-md-4 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 100%; 
 float:none;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/NfLQFRjKRc

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue people run into with Bootstrap, but one that they have provided multiple ways to solve.

Firstly, they provide a [CSS class `clearfix`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) and [Responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) which can be used to "reset" your columns at your expected breakpoints.

Secondly, if you know ahead of time that your breakpoints will all be, say, 4 columns wide, then you can simply add `</div><div class="row">` at the end of every 4th element.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix layout using [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) lib.
Just add following code:

```
$('.row').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.col-md-4'
});
```